# airflow postgresoperator transaction and commits

Tags: python, airflow, postgres-operator

From the documentation of airflow:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/_api/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres/index.html

Says this about `autocommit`:

autocommit (bool) – if True, each **command** is automatically committed. (default value: False)

So if I have two **commands**(statements), as such:

```
my_operator = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="mytask",
    postgres_conn_id="myconn",
    autocommit=True,
    sql="""

SELECT * FROM FILMS;

DELETE FROM films USING producers
  WHERE producer_id = producers.id AND producers.name = 'foo'""";
```

Does that mean this will be treated as two transactions with two commits ? Or one transation with two commits ? (guess this is not even possible). the point is if one of the statements fail will everything rollback in an atomic way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postgres` provider uses `psycopg2` as you can see in the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.html#PostgresOperator):

```py
from psycopg2.sql import SQL, Identifier
```

And if we refer to the [`autocommit` documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit):

> It is possible to set the connection in autocommit mode: this way all the commands executed will be immediately committed and no rollback is possible...

So if you put a `SELECT 1/0` in between your first and second action, I believe the first action will still be applied.

But the best way to make sure is to test it, replace the first action with an `INSERT` and the modify the delete to cancel it out. Then put a failing operation in between, run it and go see the state of your DB.